# Can a wildcard CN in an SSL certificate be more specific

Tags: ssl, certificate

Can the common name for a wild-carded SSL certificate be more specific than simply "*"?

e.g.: in the case of a firewall with multiple interfaces and similar names assigned to those interfaces: `pix-lan1`, `pix-lan2`, `pix-wan1`, etc. Is it OK to use a CN of `pix-*.domain` for a single certificate?

Clearly `*.domain` would work; but we've found that using a single wild-carded certificate enterprise wide requires the simultaneous replacement of certificates on far too many machines.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't, but you can have more than one certificate for the same CN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the protocol. For HTTPS [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#page-4) explicitly allows the wildcard character to be inside the label, i.e. something like `f*.example.com`. And I cannot find any statements in the [baseline requirements of the CA browser forum](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.3.2.pdf) that restrict the wildcard to the full label only.

For other protocols like LDAP or SMTP  the situation if different. Most allow only in the standard only full-label wildcards like `*.example.com` and don't allow `f*.example.com`. But I'm not sure how much these differences are really enforced in practice because often there is shared code for the validation of the subject.

Comment: I've discovered that the signatory we use is not happy with anything other than a solitary `*`. So `SubjectAltName` is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 6125 paragraph 6.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3) says:

3. The client MAY match a presented identifier in which the wildcard
   character is not the only character of the label (e.g.,
   baz*.example.net and *baz.example.net and b*z.example.net would
   be taken to match baz1.example.net and foobaz.example.net and
   buzz.example.net, respectively).

However, paragraph 7.2 of the same document raises security concerns.  Appendix B lists some applications and their use of wildcards.  For example, wildcard such as your example works in HTTP but not in LDAP or SMTP/POP3/IMAP.